# Spring scheduler not working at server

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-annotations, spring-scheduled

I have setup an spring scheduler service which is running on local server as expected. But when I deployed it to heroku server the scheduler service is not running.

The below is the main service:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.spring.test"})
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTest.class, args);
    }
}
```

And scheduler method is as mentioned below:

```
@Service
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
     @Scheduled(fixedRate = 900000)
     public void reminderScheduler() {
        //some tasks will execute here...
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: On local the service is running fine and not getting any error. but on server the scheduler service is not getting triggered and have no error in logs...

Comment: Is their anything which is not configured for server or something else because other API's are already running fine on same server. The only problem is with spring scheduler service.

Comment: Do you have any logging in ScheduledTasks to suggest that it is not executing. Do you have exception handling in this ScheduledTasks?

Comment: No I don't have any logging and exception handling in scheduled-tasks.

Comment: Please add that, then can we be certain if this is working or not.

Comment: added logging: Have got exception its a null pointer exception and will resolve this thanks for help

Comment: does this work using free dynos?

Comment: Yes there is no problem if you are using free dyno. I have deployed my application on heroku using free worker and it is working fine. Note: If you are using web and worker at same time the app will become idle if there is no request for 30 min on heroku.

Comment: What Spring version are you using? I found that @Scheduled annotation processor (ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor) is broken in Spring 4.1.9. It detects annotated methods, but don't launch the tasks. A workaround is to trigger onApplicationEvent method on it, that launch the tasks correctly: applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class).onApplicationEvent(new ContextRefreshedEvent(applicationContext)). It's corrected from Spring 4.2+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration seems good, you need more logging in the class `ScheduledTasks`, just to be sure that what exception is coming (if any). Spring scheduler should work in this case.